# Flutter "PathNotFoundException: can't retrieve length of file" showing in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm facing a issue while I'm uploading a selected file from draft. Say, I'm selecting a file from my iPhone and upload it. The file uploaded successfully but while I'm saving the file into Draft (into sqlite) and try to upload it sometimes its showing *PathNotFoundException: can't retrieve length of file*. Please have a look the full message into image. This happens sometimes not all the time in iPhone.

The same file don't showing any path related issue while I'm uploading it directly but found sometimes error message while I'm storing the file info into draft and upload it from draft.

[image]